# Help with iterated expectations when deriving diff-in-diff estimand

Tags: probability, expected-value, causality, conditional-expectation, difference-in-difference

[Closed, see comments]

I was reading through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01194.pdf) on recent advances in diff-in-diff and got stuck with a (probably very simple) issue when trying to derive the final population estimand.

In more detail, I'm trying to go step-by-step from this expression:

[image]

To the population estimand:

[image]

I've made a few steps, because they show that due to the no-anticipation and parallel trends assumptions:

[image]

Which then allows you to state:

$\tau_{2} = E[Y_{i,2}(1) - Y_{i,2}(0)|D_{i} = 1] = E[Y_{i,2}(1) - E[Y_{i,1} | D_{i} = 1] 
 + E[Y_{i,2}- Y_{i,1} |D_{i} = 0]|D_{i} = 1]$

I then separate out the expectations, leaving the second and third expressions, which seem problematic to me:

$E[Y_{i,2}(1) | D_{i}=1] - E[E[Y_{i,1} | D_{i}=1] + E[Y_{i,2} - Y_{i,1} | D_{i}=0] | D_{i} = 1]$

This gives the second expression as:

$E[E[Y_{i,1} | D_{i}=1]|D_{i}=1]$

Which should be equal to:

$E[Y_{i,1} | D_{i}=1]$

Since you're redundantly conditioning on D twice for the same value. But what about the third expression? We condition twice on two different values of D (which can only taken on values in {0,1}):

$E[E[Y_{i,2} - Y_{i,1}|D_{i} = 0] | D_{i} = 1]]$

My first thought would be to use the law of iterated expectations, but I'm not completely sure whether this makes any sense. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to cv :-) - most of your question seems legible to me, but could you please explain what is meant by the "LIE"? Just write it out instead of using an acronym.

Comment: Thanks :). Sorry, the law of iterated expectations:

$E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y]$

I'll edit my post to make this clearer.

Comment: I just read over this again and realized that I messed up quite badly early on. The final result follows straightforwardly if you separate the two potential outcomes straight away.